# Azure Website with RavenDb on Azure Virtual Machine - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, cloud, ravendb

I'm trying to setup a website with RavenDb on windows Azure.

I first setuped a virtual machine and started RavenDb on it. The configuration is made with IIS and Windows Authentication. I made the configuration as it is said [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/as-iis-application) and everything worked ok. I made an endpoint and was able to access the database from the virtual machine's url.

Next I tried to access the database from my application when running in Visual Studio. The connection strings I tried are similar to:

```
<add name="RavenDB" connectionString="Url=http://myRavenApp.cloudapp.net/; 
Database=MyDatabase; Domain=myRavenApp; User=RavenDbUser; Password=password" />
```

and

```
<add name="RavenDB" connectionString="Url=http://myRavenApp.cloudapp.net/; 
Database=MyDatabase; User=myRavenApp\RavenDbUser; Password=password" />
```

Both connection strings worked and my application worked like a charm.

Then I made a Website in Azure and deployed my application on it. When I did that however my application began throwing

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle specified is invalid]
System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode) +6089632
System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob) +68
System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate) +6176993
System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials) +17
System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials) +259
System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo) +159
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth() +222
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e) +223

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6115603
Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getResponse) +233
Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseString() +776
Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ExecuteRequest() +29
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectPutIndex(String name, String operationUrl, Boolean overwrite, IndexDefinition definition) +464
Raven.Client.Connection.<>c__DisplayClass3b.<PutIndex>b__3a(String operationUrl) +77
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.TryOperation(Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result) +225
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication(String method, Func`2 operation) +824
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.PutIndex(String name, IndexDefinition definition, Boolean overwrite) +185
Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask.Execute(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention documentConvention) +101
Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(ExportProvider catalogToGetnIndexingTasksFrom, IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention conventions) +154
Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(ExportProvider catalogToGetnIndexingTasksFrom, IDocumentStore documentStore) +71
Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(Assembly assemblyToScanForIndexingTasks, IDocumentStore documentStore) +115
Property.Base.DocumentManager.Initalize() +151
Property.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +177
```

So I tried with both connection strings stated above and a few others and It's always like that. I have access to the server if I try to access it from Management Studio or from my Visual Studio on debug but when I deploy on Azure Website I get this error.

If someone has an idea how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it.